# using Buffering how to play Audio player in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on Audioplayer using `AVAudioplayer`. I am completing audioplayer functionality.If i click play button the song will play.But i have some issue.i.e if I click play button the song will take time  1 to 2 mins to start the song.i am using json parser.I am using IO Buffer.But still getting same problem like to play. this is my code.please help me anybody.How to play the song immediately if user click the play button.Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)playOrPauseButtonPressed:(id)sender

{

if(playing==NO)

{

[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Here Pause.png is a image showing Pause Button.

NSError *err=nil;

AVAudioSession *audioSession=[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@ %d",urlsArray,selectedIndex);

NSString *sourcePath=[urlsArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

NSData *objectData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sourcePath]];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:objectData error:&err];

if(err)

{

NSLog(@"Error %ld,%@",(long)err.code,err.localizedDescription);

}

NSTimeInterval bufferDuration=0.005;

[audioSession setPreferredIOBufferDuration:bufferDuration error:&err];

if(err)

{

NSLog(@"Error %ld, %@", (long)err.code, err.localizedDescription);

}

double sampleRate = 44100.0;

[audioSession setPreferredSampleRate:sampleRate error:&err];

if(err)

{

NSLog(@"Error %ld, %@",(long)err.code,err.localizedDescription);

}

[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];

if(err)

{

NSLog(@"Error %ld,%@", (long)err.code, err.localizedDescription);

}

sampRate=audioSession.sampleRate;

bufferDuration=audioSession.IOBufferDuration;

NSLog(@"SampeRate:%0.0fHZI/OBufferDuration:%f",sampleRate,bufferDuration);

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

audioPlayer.delegate=self;

if(!audioPlayer.playing)

{

[audioPlayer play];

}

playing=YES;

}

else if (playing==YES)

{

[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[audioPlayer pause];

playing=NO;

}

if (self.audioPlayer)

{

[self updateViewForPlayerInfo];

[self updateViewForPlayerState];

[self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];

}

}
```

Comment: Use this library code.https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer

Comment: Of course it's going to take two minutes; your buffer is way too small. Where are you getting those numbers from? Normally you would calculate the buffer size by the sample rate, number of channels, etc.